# Splitting text contents into an array - when there is no wrapper between the block elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to scrape a bit of html and the structure is coming out like this.

//blockquote

```
<h2>1. text text</h2>
<p>1. paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>2. text text</h2>
<p>2. paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>3. text text</h2>
<p>3a. paragraph paragraph</p>
<p>3b. paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>4. text text</h2>
<p>4. paragraph paragraph</p>
```

-- so initially it was hooking into the paragraph tags - but I noticed that some blocks have more than one paragraph. At this point I am unsure how to adjust the explode function I had in place.

```
$paras = explode("<p>", $paras);
```

So the final array I need to look something more like this.

```
array(
"<p>1. paragraph paragraph</p>",
"<p>2. paragraph paragraph</p>",
"<p>3a. paragraph paragraph</p><p>3b. paragraph paragraph</p>",
"<p>4. paragraph paragraph</p>"
):
```

this is how the code currently looks

```
foreach($lookuphtml->find('blockquote') as $text) {
            $paras = $text->innertext;
            $paras = explode("<p>", $paras);
        }
```

//actual contents looks like this

```
<blockquote><h2 class="left">History</h2><p>Opened October 1997 as the first brewery in Bath since 1956.  The brewery is located in an outbuilding behind Ye Old Farmhouse public house.</p><h2 class="left">Beers Brewed</h2><p>We do not maintain a list of beers brewed by each brewery.  There may be a list on the brewery's own website and we suggest you also visit the entry for  Abbey Ales Ltd on the independent <a href="http://www.beermad.org.uk/brewery/2" rel="external" target="_blank">www.beermad.org.uk</a>.</p><h2 class="left">Regular Outlets</h2><p>The brewery has 4 pubs :</p><p>The Star, 23 Vineyards, Bath, BA1 5NA <br>The Coeur de Lion, Northumberland Place, Bath, BA1 5AR<br>The Foresters, 58 Goose Street, Beckington, Frome, BA11 6SS<br>The Assembly, 16-17 Alfred Street, Bath, BA1 2QU</p><h2 class="left">Visit Information</h2><p>Information on visit availability can be found on the breweries web site.</p><h2 class="left">Brewery Shop Information</h2><p>The brewery does not have a shop, but sells a variety of items via it's web site.</p></blockquote>
```

...Answer

never mind guys - here is the solution.

```
foreach($lookuphtml->find('blockquote') as $text) {
    $paras = $text->innertext;

    $paras = preg_replace("/<h2 class=\"left\">(.*?)<\/h2>/", "#~", $paras);
    $pa = explode("#~", $paras);
    $pa2 = array_splice($pa, 1);
}
```

Comment: -- this may work, but seems very convoluted - http://www.bitrepository.com/extract-content-between-two-delimiters-with-php.html

Comment: No its not a duplicate of that -- -- you can see from the structure - there is no wrapper to hook into -- so I need a more manual solution to tidy this up

Comment: -- but it will not extract paragraph 3 correctly - it will consider it a different element in the array - "<p>3. paragraph paragraph</p><p>3. paragraph paragraph</p>",

Comment: @PaulCrovella -- it extracts the data -- but it doesn't place the paragraphs into the correct batch.

Comment: the two paragraphs in section 3 -- will be considered the next element in the array - they don't get batched together -- there is no wrapper between the "h2 and paragraph blocks"

Comment: @PaulCrovella - I have parsed the html successfully. The problem is - that its not grouping the block paragraphs correctly. You have come up with NO technical proving answer

Comment: All current solutions/answers - bring me back to the same problem

Comment: I agree with @PaulCrovella. This is a problem that is solved by properly parsing html / walking through an html tree.

Comment: -- This is how the HTML looks -- its been parsed the way it is guys. The issue now is how to handle looping through the blocks correctly without any wrapper divs

Comment: Its not a duplicate.

Comment: @PeeHaa - found the solution

Comment: @Paul Crovella - found the solution - please provide a technical response next time.

Comment: The solution should be put in a solution box and not edited into the question.  Please move your solution to the correct location.

Comment: ^ unable to make it an answer -- its been closed off wrongly as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleXML:

```
$string = <<<XML
<root>
<h2>1. text text</h2>
<p>1. paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>2. text text</h2>
<p>2. paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>3. text text</h2>
<p>3a. paragraph paragraph</p>
<p>3b. paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>4. text text</h2>
<p>4. paragraph paragraph</p>
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$p = (array)($xml->p);

$result = [];
foreach ($p as $item) {
    preg_match('/(\d+)/', $item, $matches);
    $number = isset($matches[0]) ? $matches[0] : $item;
    $result[$number] = isset($result[$number]) ? $result[$number] : '';
    $result[$number] .= '<p>' . $item . '</p>';
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

Result is:

```
php > print_r(array_values($result));
Array
(
    [0] => <p>1. paragraph paragraph</p>
    [1] => <p>2. paragraph paragraph</p>
    [2] => <p>3a. paragraph paragraph</p><p>3b. paragraph paragraph</p>
    [3] => <p>4. paragraph paragraph</p>
)
```

Comment: -- I get that result -- and that is the problem man -- I need 3.paragraph on 2 ONLY. so [2] => 3. paragraph paragraph 3. paragraph paragraph   [3] => 4. paragraph paragraph

Comment: Edited. Added `array_unique()`

Comment: that is still missing the TWO paragraphs

Comment: I need the final output here as follows -- Array
(
    [0] => "<p>1. paragraph paragraph</p>"
    [1] => "<p>2. paragraph paragraph</p>"
    [2] => "<p>3. paragraph paragraph, 3. paragraph paragraph</p>"
    [3] => "<p>4. paragraph paragraph</p>"
)

Comment: your solution is still not right

Comment: ok, just a moment :)

Comment: -- That won't work man - we are assuming the contents of the paragraphs are the same -- so the paragraph contents for 3 could be like this "<h2>3. header </h2>
<p>3a. I like to walk amongst the trees. paragraph paragraph</p>
<p>3b. I want to build a fire. paragraph paragraph</p>"

Comment: ^ your code will fall down in this instance.. you are assuming the "contents" will be the same.

Comment: -- the numbers in the paragraphs and headers is only an example -- this is the problem man - we can't rely on the contents being unique - or there being numbers in the pattern.. -- I am going to edit the first block - then you can see what the contents looks like for real

Comment: foreach($lookuphtml->find('blockquote') as $text) {
    $paras = $text->innertext;

    $paras = preg_replace("/<h2 class=\"left\">(.*?)<\/h2>/", "#~", $paras);
    $pa = explode("#~", $paras);
    $pa2 = array_splice($pa, 1);
} -- solution man